# How to fix the dereference of a possibly null reference on getting the value of an XmlNode

Tags: c#

I am trying to read in a XML document and do some processing.

My XML looks like this, there can be plenty of `FieldProperties` elements:

```
<FieldProperties>
    <FieldName>Dietaries</FieldName>
</FieldProperties>
<FieldProperties>
    <FieldName>Transport</FieldName>
</FieldProperties>
```

What I need to do is to get all the `FieldProperties` elements, loop through them and get the text value of the `FieldName` element.

This is what I currently have:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlFields);

XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FieldProperties");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string fieldName = "";
    if (node["FieldName"] != null)
    {
        fieldName = node["FieldName"].InnerText;
    }
}
```

The warning that I am getting is on `node["FieldName"]`, it says:

```
Dereference of a possibly null reference
```

I don't understand because I am doing the null check?

How do I get it to work properly and get the warning away?

Comment: Try checking `if (node != null && node["FieldName"] != null)`

Comment: Still the same warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler can't see that the result of the indexer call is the same each time. For all it knows, you may get `null` on the second call.

Just put the node into a variable before you test it.

```cs
var n = node["FieldName"];
if (n != null)
{
    fieldName = n.InnerText;
}
```